# Downloading yahoo finance data much faster than using just a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance

I have the following code for downloading fundamental data from yahoo finance:

```
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

tickers = ('AAPL', 'MSFT', 'IBM')

infos = []
for i in tickers:
    infos.append(yf.Ticker(i).info)
```

This works actually pretty good except the fact, that the for loop takes tremendous amount of time, if I use 1000 tickers instead of just 3 like above in the example. My question is, whether there is an approach, that allows to download the info data much faster.

Answers are highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The bottleneck here likely is not your code but your internet download speed or the server you are fetching from.

Comment: @Ph.lpp Ty, I think I once heard or read that there was a way (possibly using SQL) to download the data faster and that this was not necessarily due to the server connection or the internet speed.

Comment: Have you tried with threads? These are IO operations so python threads should do the work.

Comment: @PerunSS Ty for your reply, indeed I haven't tried it with threads yet, that could be a solution, may be I'll try. may be there is also another solution, someone can recommend. Right now I am in the process of collecting suggestions, I still hope, there is a way using an sql connector in comibation with pandas datareader or somehhing like that.

Comment: @EconomistLearningPython Please compare your download speed with the amount of data you received to validate that there is a potential for improvement.

Comment: @Ph.lpp Thank you, I did compare. My download speed is much higher than the download via the for loop, I guess if there is a way to get the data by using some sql, in comparison it could be much faster and more efficient than the for loop, but unfortunately I am not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try [yahoo_fin](https://github.com/atreadw1492/yahoo_fin). i have found it to be faster.
If the number of tickers is large - then multiprocessing might be worth a look. I would recommend [Ray](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/index.html) over python multi-processing libraries.
Below are the times for 10 vs 100 tickers using each method:

```
import pandas as pd, timeit
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
import yfinance as yf
import ray
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def get_data(symbol):
    return si.get_data(ticker=symbol)

def test(tickers):
    print(f'***Testing with {len(tickers)} tickers:')

    #yfinance
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    df_res = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in tickers:
       df_res = pd.concat([df_res, yf.Ticker(i).history(period="max")])
    print(f'yfinance sync completed in: {timeit.default_timer() - start_time} seconds')  

    #yahoo_fin
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    df_res = pd.DataFrame()
    for s in tickers:
        df_res = pd.concat([df_res, si.get_data(ticker=s)])
    print(f'yahoo_fin sync completed in: {timeit.default_timer() - start_time} seconds')       

    #multi-processing
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor() #pre-initialize pool
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    df_res = pd.DataFrame()
    futures = executor.map(get_data, tickers)
    df_res = pd.concat([r for r in futures])
    print(f'concurrent.futures completed in: {timeit.default_timer() - start_time} seconds')       
    executor.shutdown()

    #ray multi processing
    ray.init(ignore_reinit_error=True) #pre-intialize
    
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    @ray.remote
    def get_data_ray(symbol):
        return si.get_data(ticker=symbol)
    result_ids = [get_data_ray.remote(s) for s in tickers]
    df_res = pd.concat(ray.get(result_ids))
    print(f'ray completed in: {timeit.default_timer() - start_time} seconds')       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #bb_persistence(symbol='SPY', st_dt='01/01/2000')
    test(tickers = ['AAPL'] * 10)
    test(tickers = ['AAPL'] * 100)
```

timing results:

```
***Testing with 10 tickers:
yfinance sync completed in: 3.9864108999609016 seconds
yahoo_fin sync completed in: 3.1445734000299126 seconds
concurrent.futures completed in: 7.356426700018346 seconds
ray completed in: 1.891160300001502 seconds

***Testing with 100 tickers:
yfinance sync completed in: 37.78823659999762 seconds
yahoo_fin sync completed in: 33.37096950004343 seconds
concurrent.futures completed in: 13.296738199947868 seconds
ray completed in: 2.770267000014428 seconds
```